# Selling Books in an iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on an iOS project where the customer wants to sell hardcopy books in the application. I did this application using [PayPal](http://kidswelcome.com.au/shop.php), but I don't think Apple will approve the PayPal user and the book will delivered to buyers by address. How can handle this?  I want also to sell ebooks and I don't know how to handle that.

Thanks!

Comment: Physical goods have to be sold (payed) using third party payment providers. Virtual goods have to be sold (payed) using Apple's payment (in-App-purchase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the developer guidelines very carefully, but there doesn't seem to be any restriction against creating apps that sell physical goods. You can't use In-app Purchasing for that, but it doesn't sound like you want to anyway:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Comment: From a technical perspective, the easiest approach might be to just create a mobile-friendly version of your existing site, and wrap it in a `UIWebView` from within an iOS app.

Comment: what about ebooks . should i put this books on itunnes , i want when the buyer buy the book send the book on his email with attach book

Comment: You will have to use in-app purchasing if you want to sell e-books. Apple will not let you sell electronic content in your app using an outside payment system.

Comment: i want to know best method to deliver ebook to buyer ?Ex : email or download ?